# How to switch tests depending on its context not in examples but in describe blocks

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I switch how to test depending on context as follows

```
> cat spec_helper.rb
def each_store(&block)
  context 'with old storage', with_elasticsearch: false do
    self.class_eval(&block)
  end

  context 'with Elasticsearch', with_elasticsearch: true do
    def case_create
        :
    end
    self.class_eval(&block)
  end
end

> cat foo_spec.rb
describe 'foo' do
 each_store do
  context 'with default settings' do
    it do |ex|
      if ex.metadata[:with_elasticsearch]
        expect(something).to match /foo/
      else
        expect(something).not_to match /foo/
      end
    end
  end
 end
end
```

but isn't it possible to switch not in example blocks but describe and context block such as

```
describe 'foo' do
  context 'with default settings' do |c|
    if c.metadata[:with_elasticsearch]
      it 'should match'
    else
      it 'should not match'
    end
  end
end
```

as I'd like to use different strings as the first argument of it method depending on the store.